# Javascript code not running after the page is refreshed or reloaded

Tags: javascript, checkbox, reload, checked

I have a javascript code that, whenever a checkbox is checked, will reload my current page and then is supposed to grey out some input fields.

However, it is only doing the reload when the page is reloaded the input fields are never greyed out.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#storePickUp").on("click", function () {
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
document.getElementById("shippingForm").submit();   
document.getElementById("shippingAdress").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("shippingState").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("shippingCity").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("shippingZip").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("shippingZipCode").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("shippingButton").disabled = true;
}
});
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in your code on the 4th line where you call .submit()... unless you have some extra magic on the page that you are not showing, this line will proceed to post/get your form to whatever url you have configured in that form.

What this means is that the lines underneath that do not matter at all, since they will not be executed on the forms target page.

To get around this if you truly need the form post in the middle, you would need to post to a specific url and use that url as a trigger on page load to disable those elements.  Not directly after the click, but rather on the newly loaded page that is the target of the form... make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because it's only disabling them when you click on #storePickUp but if your page is reloaded it will reset.

Answer (score 0):

Method `submit` is executed, page reloads, code after `submit` is never executed. Even if that code would be executed, page refresh nullifies any changes.

You should probably do submitting with `ajax`, not with `submit` method. If you are using jQuery, it will make it easy for you:

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/